# Getting import error in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalender
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
usb =CustomBusinessDay(calender=USFederalHolidayCalender())
usb
```

Error- ImportError: cannot import name 'USFederalHolidayCalender' from 'pandas.tseries.holiday' (c:\users\shivh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\holiday.py)

Comment: Just a typo: `USFederalHolidayCalender` -> `USFederalHolidayCalendar`

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo it is USFederalHolidayCalendar replace 'e' with 'a' in Calendar.